# How to get working directory of jinja2 loader?

Tags: python-3.x, jinja2, airflow

I am trying to create an airflow workflow that generates html reports using jinja2 with airflow. The template is sitting under `./dags/report_generator/template.html`.

I am trying to load it up within `./dags/report_generator/generator.py` in this way:

```
loader = FileSystemLoader("/dags/report_generator")
env = Environment(loader=loader)
template = env.get_template("template.html")
```

This fails with the following error:

```
    template = env.get_template("report.html")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 830, in get_template
    return self._load_template(name, self.make_globals(globals))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 804, in _load_template
    template = self.loader.load(self, name, globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 113, in load
    source, filename, uptodate = self.get_source(environment, name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/jinja2/loaders.py", line 187, in get_source
    raise TemplateNotFound(template)
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: template.html
```

I tried various combinations of the path in `loader` as well as `get_template` code. I have a feeling the loader is pointing somewhere else than I think it is.

Is there a way I can run "print working directory" of where the loader is pointing?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I used to do something like:

```
init_env = Environment(auto_reload=False)
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '../', 'templates', templates_sub_dir)
init_env.loader = FileSystemLoader(path)
```

Where templates is in the root dir of your project.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I tried this out without success

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this problem and just found a pretty solid workaround. After you create your `Environment`, try calling

`env.loader.list_templates()`

This should list all of the templates found by the `FileSystemLoader`, and the list of files should give you a good idea of where the "working directory" is.